# Unwanted chart changes over time in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

**Intro:**

I am having a chart (`"myChart"`) in `Excel` which has two dataseries within.
Via `Formula > Name Manager` both dataseries correspond to defined data columns within the sheet.
Those columns change their length via input data (>snippet 1) and therefore the chart shall dynamically change its form. After giving the input for the column changes I manually run the `CustomLabels()` macro for changing the labeling of my maxima values (`"Batch"`).
The display of the chart happens without problems and changes accordingly (first picture).

***Snippet 1***
`=OFFSET(Book1.xlsm!Name1;0;0;COUNTA(Sheet1!$G:$G)-1;1)`

***myChart***
[image: myChart - wanted outcome]

**Labelling Macro**

```vb
Sub CustomLabels()

   Dim i, myCount, pt
   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Activate
   myCount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count

   For i = 2 To myCount
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = Range("I" & i + 6).Value
   Next i

   ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Activate
   myCount = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points.Count

   For i = 2 To myCount
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
       ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(i).DataLabel.Text = Range("O" & i + 6).Value
   Next i

End Sub
```

**Problems:**

*1) Axis*

Although my axis labes column is in custom format `DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm`, the axis datalabels look as displayed in the picture above.
Is this a format error or what do I have to do?

*2) Unwanted chart change*

After working wihtin the workbook/sheet and changing values (non-dependent on the chart or vice-versa), the chart changes and looks like in the picture below. Selecting a cell containing chart-data and pressing enter (no changes needed) the chart changes back to the above picture.
What can be the reasons for that?

**myChart after saving/working within the sheet**
[image: myChart - unwanted change]

Comment: If you check the axis options you will find Axis Types .. I select Text Axis when I have to deal with hours and minutes. Minimum base unit available for date axis is a day. That makes it look weird as the chart is not showing series line for every hour:min values. .. [Link here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/db036e1d-247e-412a-b733-17752ab016dc/how-can-i-build-a-graph-with-a-time-axis-based-on-minutesseconds-milli-seconds-excel2010)

Comment: and [also this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other-mso_2016/change-the-base-unit-that-is-displayed-on-a-date/79108baa-2b7c-4ab8-96dc-ec8df0baab38)  ,,,, and [this](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-charting-and-pivots/474629-i-want-my-x-axis-to-have-5-10-minute-intervals.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CustomLabels()

    Dim j, i, cols
    Dim my_chart As Chart, sc As Series
    
    Set my_chart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart").Chart
    
    With my_chart.Axes(xlCategory)   ' axis adjustment
        .CategoryType = xlCategoryScale ' not XlCategoryType.xlAutomaticScale | XlCategoryType.xlTimeScale
        .TickLabels.NumberFormat = "DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm"
        .TickLabels.Orientation = xlUpward
    End With
    
    cols = Array("I", "O")  'columns containing labels
    For j = 1 To my_chart.SeriesCollection.Count
        Set sc = my_chart.SeriesCollection(j)
    
        For i = 2 To sc.Points.Count
            sc.Points(i).ApplyDataLabels
            sc.Points(i).DataLabel.Text = Range(cols(j - 1) & i + 6).Value
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the correction of the axis labels and correct sorting of the data series labels hinders the chart from changing. So both problems fixed with one code correction. Thanks!